# Формы прилагательного

Tags: морфология

Какие качественные прилагательные, обозначающие цвет, имеют краткие формы?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вопрос: Вас интересуют цвета или всё-таки оттенки цветов?

Answer (score 2):

Как это? Цвет имеет краткую форму? Может, Вы все-таки о словах? Будьте, пожалуйста, внимательнее к формулировке вопроса. И лучше бы спросить о конкретных словах, ведь оттенков (а Вы не цвета имеете в виду, а оттенки) огромное количество!

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы имеете в виду цвета, то НЕ имеют краткой формы  ***оранжевый, палевый, фисташковый*** (примеры отсюда:http://mariab.h1.ru/index.files/RuLang/morfol/adj7.html). Слова "голубой" и "золотой" в краткой форме употребляются крайне **редко**.

Ещё у Розенталя (http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/58.htm):
Названия некоторых цветов или **мало**употребительны в краткой форме (голубой, коричневый, розовый, фиолетовый и др.), или употребляются с известными **ограничениями**. Так, почти совсем не встречаются формы мужского рода бур, синь (при употребительности форм женского и среднего рода и множественного числа).

**Дополнение к ответу.**

**После всего сказанного по теме** *совершенно очевидно, что ответить на предложенный вопрос можно только опираясь на авторитетные словари и другие источники, потому как в художественной литературе окказионализмы встречаются сплошь и рядом по вполне понятным причинам.*

§ 1332. Поскольку семантические ограничения при образовании *кратких форм* **не относятся** к числу **строгих** **правил**, ***в языке художественной литературы эти ограничения могут сниматься.*** Здесь **постоянно** фиксируются **не** отмечаемые в словарях и грамматиках, а также **окказиональные** употребления кратких форм: Как хорошо показалось небо, как **голубо**, спокойно и глубоко! (Л. Толст.); Перерытая земля огородов была **лилова** (Фед.); Скатерть, несмотря на пушки и на все это томление, тревогу и чепуху, бела и **крахмальна** (Булг.); Тотчас же физиономии этой ассамблеи стали важны, **кукольны** и надменны (Леон.); И дневной воздух меден, И ночной воздух лунный То же самое вреден, Ибо он как чугунный (Март.); Одну вашу вещь я отправил вам обратно... Она не годится, потому что она совсем не **фортепианна** (С. Рахманинов); Так же **"дневниковы"** и доверительны стихи, говорящие о творчестве, о долге художника (Газ.)
http://rusgram.narod.ru/1315-1341.html#1336.

Comment: "Оранжев" вполне, имхо, возможно. А вот "голуб" - в м.р. невозможно без всяких оговорок.
Я только не понял насчет "оттенков" у автора.

Comment: Простите, я неправильно сформулировал вопрос.

Comment: Так возьмите и поправьте. Свой вопрос Вы же можете редактировать!

Comment: Поискала "оранжев" в интернете. "Долг платежом оранжев" - ну, это журналистский прием. А вот еще стихи (вполне себе неплохие):  

Мандариновый сад откровенно оранжев,  
виноградная кисть невозможно легка.  
Ты целуешь меня. (Целовала и раньше,  
но чуть-чуть аккуратней, чуть-чуть свысока).  
 . . . .
Дмитрий Артис.  
В стихах, кстати, можно то, что нельзя в прозе. Наверное, и "голуб" где-то есть.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то краткие формы в основном имеют те названия цветов (оттенков), которые употребимы в переносном значении - и таким образом гораздо чаще могут выступать в роли предикатива: cер, бел, красен, черен. При этом краткие формы мужского рода по фонетическим причинам используются реже всех остальных.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос, наверное, должен был выглядеть так: Какие прилагательные, обозначающие оттенки цветов  , могут иметь краткую форму?
Ответ: зеленоват, жёлтоват, cероват, беловат, красноват, черноват, оранжеват, голубоват, коричневат, розоват, буроват.
ernest0, но в вопросе речь идёт не о м. р. прилаг., а о краткой форме  оттенков. Фиолетоват же не скажешь.Или я чего-то не поняла?

Comment: Инна,позвольте, но вы ведь в каждом  кратком прилагательном используете суффикс "оват/еват".С ними никаких затруднений не возникает,собственно..

Comment: Почему только на "-оват"? Например, "малинов". Закат малинов. Да и другие наверное есть.  
Я читала книжку Р.Фрумкиной "Цвет, смысл, сходство". Они в эксперименте выделяли 110 слов-цветообозначений. А еще сколько можно придумать модификаций (та же "-оватость", например!)  

Чудная, кстати, книга. Я, как математик, ее очень люблю.

Comment: А слова типа изжелта-красный, иссиня - черный, серо-голубой - разве не оттенки? Вполне допускаю "изжелта-красен", а вот "серо-голуб"? Прилагательные, обозначающие цвет, относятся к качественным прилагательным и теоретически могут иметь краткую форму, а практически все-таки употребление ограничено традицией. Нарушение традиций в художественной литературе - источник образности, красивости.

Answer (score 0):

Пара ссылок на национальный корпус русского языка.

**Оранжев**

1. И. Грекова. Фазан (1984)   [омонимия снята]
   Вот уже парта расколота на мелкие части, пылает печная топка, яркий огонь оранжев, и в нём сгорает всё― и преступление, и ложь, и Варины слёзы, и даже стихи про волков… [И. Грекова. Фазан (1984)] [омонимия снята]
2. Торговый ряд (2004) // «Амурский Меридиан» (Хабаровск), 2004.12.22   [омонимия не снята]
   Телефон сотовый «Сименс А-55», съемная панель, оранжев. подсветка, за 2500 руб. [Торговый ряд (2004) // «Амурский Меридиан» (Хабаровск), 2004.12.22] [омонимия не снята]
3. Василий Аксенов. Апельсины из Марокко (1962)   [омонимия не снята]
   Он был бугрист, оранжев и словно светился. [Василий Аксенов. Апельсины из Марокко (1962)] [омонимия не снята]

Пример 2 сразу снимаю :-) В нем явно используется сокращение. Пример 1 предлагаю обсудить (может *оранжев* - это существительное?)

**Голуб** там же не нашел в нужном нам контексте.